# Using " as shortcut with babel

Tags: babel, catcodes, shorthands

I try to use `"` as a shortcut by using

```
\catcode`\"=13
\newcommand*{"}[1]{^{(#1)}}
```

I have to use babel[german] but the package destroys with my shortcut.

Is ther any way to prevent this or do I have to use another character?

**Edit**
I just had to place the commands inside the document and not the preamble. now everything works fine.

Comment: If you do not use the babel part, disable it. It us explained in the babel manual (look for shorthands)

Comment: `\shorthandoff{"}`?

Comment: that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

It's a timing problem: `babel` changes the meaning of `"` at begin document, so you should add your redefinition after that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\shorthandoff{"}

\begingroup
\catcode`"=\active
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand{"}[1]{^{(#1)}}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

$f"{2}$

\end{document}
```

My advice is *not* to do this and to keep the shorthands.

[image]